# How to app delete in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

- How to iTunes connect app remove
- Without uploaded app in app store remove
- Without any submit for review
- only One time build uploaded

Comment: What do you mean, removing a build from IC ?

Comment: Not a remove a build I remove app for itunes connect

Comment: rckoenes but i not upload any build to submit for Review

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my question I got back from Apple support.

You can only delete an app from the App Store if it was previously approved (meaning has one approved version).

From [iTunes Connect Developer Guide - Transferring and Deleting Apps:](https://developer.apple.com/support/itunes-connect/)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the app easily

> If the Delete App button isn’t displayed, check that you’re the team agent and that the app is in one of the statuses that allow the app to be deleted.

[Check Details from Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Answer (score 0):

App can be deleted from iTunesConnect only after app is submitted for review.